# D3Node getComputedTextLength() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am using d3node to render a chart on the server. I have one function that needs to wrap text.

```
wrapText(textArray, width) {
    textArray.each(function () {
        const text = d3.select(this);
        const words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse();
        const lineHeight = 1.1;
        const x = text.attr('x');
        const y = text.attr('y');
        const dy = 0;

        let word = '';
        let line = [];
        let lineNumber = 0;
        let tspan = text.text(null)
            .append('tspan')
            .attr('x', x)
            .attr('y', y)
            .attr('dy', `${dy + lineHeight * (lineNumber += 1)}em`);
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(' '));

            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(' '));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append('tspan')
                    .attr('x', x)
                    .attr('y', y)
                    .attr('dy', `${dy + lineHeight * (lineNumber += 1)}em`)
                    .text(word);
            }
        }
    });
},
```

When I console.log d3.select(this); I get HTMLUnknownElement and bunch of properties. Now when it comes to tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() it fails with getComputedTextLength() is not a function.

Code that is cdallig wrap function is this

```
       comment
            .append('text')
            .attr('class', 'comment-text')
            .attr('fill', '#000')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
            .text(text)
            .style('font-family', "'Roboto','Open Sans', sans-serif")
            .call(this.wrapText, this.height - 100);'
```

The same thing happens here:

```
    comment
            .select('.comment-text')
            .selectAll('tspan')
            .each(function calculateTextSize() {
                if (this.getComputedTextLength() > textHeight) {
                    textHeight = this.getComputedTextLength();
                }
            });
```

This code is working perfectly on the client, the problem is with D3node. Did anyone had the same problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm also working with D3Node and stuck not he same issue

Comment: @Craig Unforutenetly no, because d3node is using jsdom, and in this case, we need real dom and not virtual.

Answer (score 2):

When using React this works for me:

```
describe("your test suite", () => {
  const originalGetComputedTextLength =
    SVGElement.prototype.getComputedTextLength
  beforeEach(
    () =>
      (SVGElement.prototype.getComputedTextLength = () => {
        return 150
      })
  )
  afterEach(
    () =>
      (SVGElement.prototype.getComputedTextLength = originalGetComputedTextLength)
  )

  it("your test case", async () => {
    ...
```

Comment: The above worked for me. I also had to do the following to fix a separate issue: 
`SVGElement.prototype.transform = { baseVal: { consolidate: () => {} } };`